# Json parsing.. force closing error

Tags: android, json

i get this error whenever i tried to open this app it is force closing everytime....
i'm parsing the data from my local host.i'm not getting what is the error.. I am new in android and i am not good in reading the logcat either
can anyone solve this.... thanks before...

**MainActivity:**

```
package com.newjson;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static String url = "http://10.0.2.2:80/sample/";

    private static final String TAG_RESPONSE = "response";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "RetailerName";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "Email";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE = "Phone";
    private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "Address";

    JSONArray response = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        JSONObject jobj = parser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try{
            response = jobj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESPONSE);

            JSONObject c = response.getJSONObject(0);

            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
            String phone = c.getString(TAG_PHONE);
            String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);

            TextView name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView email1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);
            TextView phone1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.phone);
            TextView address1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.address);

            name1.setText(name);
            email1.setText(email);
            phone1.setText(phone);
            address1.setText(address);
        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**JSONParser**:

```
package com.newjson;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream; 
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.util.Log;

    public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jobj = null;
    static String json = "";

    public JSONParser(){

    }
    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url){
        try{
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost();
            HttpResponse respose = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity entity = respose.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(ClientProtocolException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while((line = br.readLine())!= null){
                sb.append(line + "\n");

            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("buffer error", "error converting result"+e.toString());
        }
        return jobj;
    }

}
```

**Logcat:**

```
11-26 12:15:50.296: D/AndroidRuntime(639): Shutting down VM
11-26 12:15:50.296: W/dalvikvm(639): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception        (group=0x40015560)
11-26 12:15:50.330: E/AndroidRuntime(639): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-26 12:15:50.330: E/AndroidRuntime(639): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.newjson/com.newjson.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 12:15:50.330: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
11-26 12:15:50.330: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
11-26 12:15:50.330: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-26 12:15:50.330: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-26 12:15:50.330: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-26 12:15:50.330: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-26 12:15:50.330: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-26 12:15:50.330: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 12:15:50.330: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-26 12:15:50.330: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-26 12:15:50.330: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-26 12:15:50.330: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-26 12:15:50.330: E/AndroidRuntime(639): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 12:15:50.330: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at  org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.determineTarget(AbstractHttpClient.java:496)
11-26 12:15:50.330: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
11-26 12:15:50.330: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
11-26 12:15:50.330: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at com.newjson.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:31)
11-26 12:15:50.330: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at com.newjson.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
11-26 12:15:50.330: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-26 12:15:50.330: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
11-26 12:15:50.330: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  ... 11 more
```

This is what always coming:
[image]

Comment: It is a good idea to first `Log` your JSON string.

Comment: your jobj is getting null from jsonparser..

Comment: sorry i didn't get you... bcz i'm new in android json parsing... can you explain it ?

Comment: First of all, you should do your network operations in an AsyncTask or a Thread. Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: add chrome extension advance rest client and then test your url over there as far as i know issue is with url if its get request then url is not working. Debug your code and check jobj is null or not in my case it is null so exception occurs .

Comment: Where is `JSONParser` ? Post the codes of `JSONParser`

Comment: @BatuhanC I think he's using Jackson JSON parser library.

Comment: @Sufian I don't think he is using it check the imports and see that line `at com.newjson.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:31)`

Comment: this is my Json parser

Comment: @aswin post line 31 of your `com.newjson.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl()`. The problem is there as BatuhanC noted.

Comment: can anyone post simple complete parsing code..that 'll help me much better..

Comment: I posted an answer, check that.

Comment: also my prob is it is not fetching data from my local host ... i think i dont have any mistakes in my MainActivity.java code...

Answer (score 0):

Your post variable throw a null pointer exception in this line

```
 HttpPost post = new HttpPost();
```

just add the url as a parameter

```
 HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `HttpPost`, the thing you want to do is `HttpGet`. Change your `getJSONFromUrl` method with;

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url){
    try{
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse respose = client.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = respose.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(ClientProtocolException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while((line = br.readLine())!= null){
            sb.append(line + "\n");

        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("buffer error", "error converting result"+e.toString());
    }
    return jobj;
}
```

Finally you must do your network operations on AsyncTask. Change your MainActivity codes with;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static String url = "http://10.0.2.2:80/sample/";

    private static final String TAG_RESPONSE = "response";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "RetailerName";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "Email";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE = "Phone";
    private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "Address";
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private YourTask task;

    JSONArray response = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        task = new YourTask();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Downloading...",true ,false);
        task.execute();

    }

    public class YourTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {   
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject jobj = parser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return jobj;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jobj) {
            try{
                response = jobj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESPONSE);

                JSONObject c = response.getJSONObject(0);

                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                String phone = c.getString(TAG_PHONE);
                String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);

                TextView name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
                TextView email1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);
                TextView phone1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.phone);
                TextView address1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.address);

                name1.setText(name);
                email1.setText(email);
                phone1.setText(phone);
                address1.setText(address);
            }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            task = null;
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but i think the person who have downvoted my answer must make an explanation! Because i think this answer is correct. If i have any mistake, i want to know it.

Comment: @BatuhanC as you said i did everything ...but while getting data it is stoping unfortunately... can you help in that prob..

Comment: You can use debug mode and breakpoints on your ide to realize the problem on your code. Also tell us about your new LogCat.

Comment: ya i used the debug mode it is showing the error is in this line.. array = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);  But i have gave the json array name correct only - @BatuhanC

Comment: In the question you posted, there is no line like that. I can not see.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129009/json-parsing-unfortunately-closing-error... sry i have done changes in my app and i posted that completely in this